# Postgres - How to order/rank by coincidences in a query with or

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I perform the following query

```
select * from table where c2 = 11 or c3 = 15 or c7 = false
```

I'm getting this result

```
| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4  | c5  | c6      | c7     | c8        |
| 24 | 11 | 15 | NNN | NNN |         | true   | false     |
| 28 | 11 | 13 | NNN | NNN |         | true   | false     |
| 26 | 11 | 15 | NNN | NNN | wwwww   | false  | false     |
| 25 | 11 | 2  | NNN | NNN | qqqq    | false  | false     |
| 33 | 23 | 31 | NNN | NNN |         | false  | false     |
| 31 | 23 | 15 | NNN | NNN |         | false  | false     |
| 31 | 23 | 15 | NNN | NNN |         | true   | false     |
| 25 | 11 | 23 | NNN | NNN | qqqqw2  | false  | false     |
| 29 | 11 | 22 | NNN | NNN |         | true   | false     |
```

I'm trying to order this by search coincidences, like this:

```
| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4  | c5  | c6      | c7    | c8        |
| 26 |[11]|[15]| NNN | NNN | wwwww   |[false]| false     |
| 24 |[11]|[15]| NNN | NNN |         | true  | false     |
| 25 |[11]| 2  | NNN | NNN | qqqq    |[false]| false     |
| 31 | 23 |[15]| NNN | NNN |         |[false]| false     |
| 25 |[11]| 23 | NNN | NNN | qqqqw2  |[false]| false     |
| 28 |[11]| 13 | NNN | NNN |         | true  | false     |
| 29 |[11]| 22 | NNN | NNN |         | true  | false     |
| 31 | 23 |[15]| NNN | NNN |         | true  | false     |
| 33 | 23 | 31 | NNN | NNN |         |[false]| false     |
```

So the row that has the 3 options will be on top
then the all the rows that matches at least 2 optiones (in no specific order)
and last all the rows that matches 1 option,

Is there a way to achieve this order? because the other option I have is doing combination of options with and statement and then use union with all the results, but it seems to be a lot more

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an order by clause:

```
order by (case when c2 = 11 then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when c3 = 15 then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when c7 = false then 1 else 0 end) desc
```

([SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/cce83/3))

Comment: Thanks for your response. One more question, lets suppose my table has 20 columns (as an example), and my query will use 9 columns. Do I have to do this?

Comment: @JavierQQ23 . . . I'm not sure what you means by "Do I have to do this?".  If you want the results ordered, then you need an `order by` clause.  If you want them ordered by the number of column matches, then you need something a lot like this.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, if I have 9 more options do I have to write each case line?. I'm wondering if postgres can do that kind of rank by itself or maybe I'm asking too much :). Anyway thanks again

Comment: @JavierQQ23 . . . Well yes.  Or you can take the approach suggested by Clodoaldo, although I think the `case` statement is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
order by
    (c2 = 11)::integer + (c3 = 15)::integer + (not c7)::integer desc
```

[Stealing from @Gordon's example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/cce83/6)

Comment: Thanks for your alternative :)